# ListFragment won't replace ListFragment when list item click

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm working on an app which has a FragmentPagerAdapter which shows a ListFragment. If a user clicks on an item in the list I'm trying to perform a FragmentTransaction and replace the current Fragment with the next one.

However, when I attempt to switch the fragment within the onItemClick, nothing happens, there is no error but the list fragment doesn't change. I've attached the relevant code of what I'm currently trying. I think it's because I'm using the wrong fragmentManager but I'm unsure how to get the correct one.

---

A FragmentPagerAdapter that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary sections of the app.

```
public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
                // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.
                return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();

            case 1:
                return new LibrarySectionFragment();

            case 2:
                return new LipshapeSectionFragment();


            default:
                // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Practice";
            case 1:
                return "Library";
            case 2:
                return "Help";
        }

        return "Untitled";
    }
}
```

Here is the ListFragment which has the onClick

```
public static class LipshapeSectionFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_library, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ContentResolver resolver = this.getContext().getContentResolver();

        //  if you only want one column do it like this
        // String[] projection = new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, VideoFilesContract.videoFiles.FILENAME};
        Cursor lipshapeCursor =
                resolver.query(LipshapeContract.lipshapes.CONTENT_URI,
                        LipshapeContract.lipshapes.PROJECTION_ALL,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        lipshapeCursor.moveToFirst();

        // Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
        LipshapeCursorAdapter lipshapeAdapter = new LipshapeCursorAdapter(this.getContext(), lipshapeCursor);
        // Attach cursor adapter to the ListView

        setListAdapter(lipshapeAdapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
    {
        Cursor cursor  = ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position));

        ContentResolver resolver = this.getContext().getContentResolver();

        Cursor wordCursor =
                resolver.query(WordContract.wordItems.CONTENT_URI,
                        WordContract.wordItems.PROJECTION_ALL,
                        "lipshape_id=?",
                        new String[]{cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))},
                        null);

        int count = wordCursor.getCount();

        TestSectionFragment fragment = new TestSectionFragment();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.lvLibrary, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Words within this group: " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

The layout file for the ListFragment (fragment_section_library):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lvLibrary"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

A test Fragment I'm trying to replace the ListFragment with:

```
 */
public static class TestSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                "Test Worked");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The layout file for the TestFragment (fragment_section_dummy):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="24sp"
android:padding="32dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the problem. The main issue is that you have to programatically add a fragment before you can replace it, here is the changes needed to fix the issues, it shows a listview, which is replaced with another listview on listItem click:

```
/**
     * A lipshape list fragment
     */
    public static class LipshapeSectionFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
    {

    public LipshapeCursorAdapter lipshapeAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_library, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ContentResolver resolver = this.getContext().getContentResolver();

        //  if you only want one column do it like this
        // String[] projection = new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, VideoFilesContract.videoFiles.FILENAME};
        Cursor lipshapeCursor =
                resolver.query(LipshapeContract.lipshapes.CONTENT_URI,
                        LipshapeContract.lipshapes.PROJECTION_ALL,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);


        // Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
        lipshapeAdapter = new LipshapeCursorAdapter(this.getContext(), lipshapeCursor);
        // Attach cursor adapter to the ListView

        //setListAdapter(lipshapeAdapter);
        //getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(lipshapeAdapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
    {
        Cursor cursor  = ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position));

        ContentResolver resolver = this.getContext().getContentResolver();

        Cursor wordCursor =
                resolver.query(WordContract.wordItems.CONTENT_URI,
                        WordContract.wordItems.PROJECTION_ALL,
                        "lipshape_id=?",
                        new String[]{cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))},
                        null);

        int count = wordCursor.getCount();

        WordListSectionFragment fragment = new WordListSectionFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString("lipshape_selected", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.svBody, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();


        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Words within this group: " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
}
```

WordListFragment

```
    /**
     * 
     * WordListFragment
     */
    public static class WordListSectionFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_wordlist, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            ContentResolver resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();

            Bundle args = getArguments();

            Cursor wordCursor =
                    resolver.query(WordContract.wordItems.CONTENT_URI,
                            WordContract.wordItems.PROJECTION_ALL,
                            "lipshape_id=?",
                            new String[]{args.getString("lipshape_selected")},
                            null);

            wordCursor.moveToFirst();

            // Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
            WordCursorAdapter wordAdapter = new WordCursorAdapter(this.getContext(), wordCursor);
            // Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
            setListAdapter(wordAdapter);
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

        }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,long id)
            {
                Cursor cursor  = ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position));

                String test = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));
                int word_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CollectionDemoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("word_id", word_id);
                startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

        }
    }
```

LibrarySectionFragment

```
    /**
     *
     * A library fragment
     */
    public static class LibrarySectionFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            LipshapeSectionFragment fragment = new LipshapeSectionFragment();

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.svBody, fragment).commit();

            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

The major change comes with the first list fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lvLibrary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then next we have the base fragment it sits within:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/svBody"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

</LinearLayout>
```